# Reachability test failed while network is on LTE

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, networking, lte

1. Some users (on a particular carrier, using 4g) of my apps cannot load photos.
2. And the reachability test also failed. But I can access some of my backend APIs with no issues.
3. But this never happens when I test my app with WiFi.

What could cause this problem?

Code for reachability test:

```
- (IBAction)fbButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"http://www.google.com"];

    // Internet is reachable
    __weak id weakSelf = self;
    internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [weakSelf showLoadingIndicators];
            [[User sharedInstance] attemptToLoginToFB];
            [[Mixpanel sharedInstance] track:@"Try to login using FB"];
        });
    };

    // Internet is not reachable
    internetReachableFoo.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Unavailable"
                                                            message:@"Try again when you are connected."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alertView show];

        });
    };

    [internetReachableFoo startNotifier];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

4G networks are new and often use different network equipment than the same carriers 3G network so this could easily be a carrier problem rather than a problem with your app. If you are only seeing this in 4G and not in 3G then I would investigate other carriers also to see if the issues exist there, and if not then I would check with the problem carriers technical support team - if you can give them the exact URL you are using to download the photos then they should be able to test it quickly.

You could also try testing using a REST client on a PC connected to that carrier if you have a 4G dongle for their network (and assuming you are using some sort of REST interface to access the functionality on your servers). If this fails just on their network, again their technical team should be able to trouble shoot it very quickly (you will have effectively done a lot of the hard work for them, which most of them will appreciate).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Any idea why some part of my API works? And If I open safari in the same network condition, I can browse with no issue.

Comment: Unfortunately there could be many reasons, for example the photos may exceed some size criteria that has been incorrectly set in the network someplace; your app may be similar to some peer to peer app that the operator is blocking and they are inadvertently catching some of your traffic also etc. If it really is just on this particular 4G network, I would gather some specific examples and contact their tech help. Let us know what the outcome is in case it is a more general or app specific problem.